# MySQL Query execution is taking long time to execute

Tags: mysql

I used the following MySQL query to select some records from tables.

```
 select 
        main.fees_id, 
        main.month,
        main.fee,
        main.status as fees_status,
        off1.*,off2.*,off3.*,
       
        SUM(off4.amount) as payback_amount,
        SUM(off4.issued_amount) as issued_amount,

        (SELECT COUNT(fees_fees_verify.id) FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
        fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Verified") AND 
        fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as verified_count,

        (SELECT fees_fees_verify.amount FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
        fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Confirmed") AND 
        fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as confirmed_amount,

        (SELECT fees_fees_verify.amount FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
        fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Declined", "Deleted") AND 
        fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as declined_amount
       
        
       from fees_fees as main
        left join fees_locgov as off1 on main.locgov=off1.locgov_id
       left join fees_court as off2 on main.court=off2.court_id
       left join fees_office as off3 on main.registrar=off3.fees_office_id
        left join fees_payback_fees as off4 on main.fees_id=off4.fees_fees 
        left join fees_fees_verify as off5 on main.fees_id=off5.fees_id
       
        group by main.fees_id
        order by main.month, main.fees_id
```

### Issues

The query is executing correctly. But taking at least 5 minutes to generate the result. All the tables and joins in the query is required to get the expected result.

### Tried

Created indexes for main.fees_id and fees_fees_verify.id. But the execution time not reduced. What can do for this query to reduce the ececution time ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please share the result of `explain select main ....`

Comment: you have to share AT LEAST the `EXPLAIN ...` output, even better, your entire schema and roughly the size of each table

Comment: And you should add indexes for columns you use in  `where` conditions

Comment: @ juergen d. There are no WHERE conditions in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too many subqueries. You can change all the part with those subqueries:

```
(SELECT COUNT(fees_fees_verify.id) FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Verified") AND 
fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as verified_count,

(SELECT fees_fees_verify.amount FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Confirmed") AND 
fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as confirmed_amount,

(SELECT fees_fees_verify.amount FROM fees_fees_verify WHERE 
fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Declined", "Deleted") AND 
fees_fees_verify.fees_id=main.fees_id) as declined_amount
```

With a code using case statements instead of subqueries:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fees_fees_verify.status="Verified" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS verified_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN fees_fees_verify.status="Confirmed" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS confirmed_amount,
SUM(CASE WHEN fees_fees_verify.status IN ("Declined", "Deleted") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS declined_amount,
```

An the reason is because for each one of your rows, you are executing 3 subqueries to look for the values, while you already have them and just have to check for them.

Besides that, maybe you should change your **GROUP BY** expression to include all columns that are not using an aggregate function.